GCP text-to-speech synthesize long audio returns SpeechErrorSpace::TTS_BACKEND_REQUEST_RPC_ERROR
I am using the golang client to convert long texts (>10000 characters) to audio. It used to work pretty good but now I'm getting these errors:

waiting for operation: rpc error: code = Internal desc = INTERNAL:  [type.googleapis.com/util.ErrorSpacePayload='SpeechErrorSpace::TTS_BACKEND_REQUEST_RPC_ERROR']

    request := texttospeechpb.SynthesizeLongAudioRequest{
        Input: &texttospeechpb.SynthesisInput{
            InputSource: &texttospeechpb.SynthesisInput_Text{
                Text: text,
            },
        },
        Voice: &texttospeechpb.VoiceSelectionParams{
            LanguageCode: languageCode,
            Name:         voice,
        },
        Parent: "projects/######/locations/us-central1",
        AudioConfig: &texttospeechpb.AudioConfig{
            AudioEncoding: texttospeechpb.AudioEncoding_LINEAR16,
        },
        OutputGcsUri: targetItem.String(),
    }

    operation, err := n.speechClient.SynthesizeLongAudio(ctx, &request)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("synthesizing audio: %w", err)
    }

When I only do one request at a time, everything works fine, but I would like to parallelize it.

Based on this public document for RPC reference if you encountered “INTERNAL” errors, This means that some invariants expected by the underlying system have been broken. This error code is reserved for serious errors.
Google Cloud Platform Support offers support packages to meet your needs such as to have access to a technical support manager for further assistance into your project.
For parallel execution we can use goroutines.
func synthesizeAudio(text string, languageCode string, voice string, targetGcsUri string) (string, error) {
    // ... your existing logic ...
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup 
    for _, text := range texts { 
        wg.Add(1) 
        go func(text string) { 
            defer wg.Done() 
            // Call synthesizeAudio with the current text 
        }(text) 
    } 
    wg.Wait() 
}

This example demonstrates how to use goroutines to concurrently call synthesizeAudio for each text in the text slice.
